# Preview in High Sierra not functioning properly

Tags: macbook-pro, pdf, preview

I am suddenly finding certain strange behaviors in Preview app Version 10.0 (944.4). Current OS version is High Sierra 10.13.3.

1) On selecting a section in Table of Contents, the selection gets switched to preceding section.
[image]

2) Clicking on an item in annotations window doesn't take me to its respective page, nor they open the popups or notes that's already written. What's the use of this Annotations window now??? Earlier this used to work well.

3) Annotations block sentences (Please take a look at the square box that on clicking opens a note).
[image]

Comment: did you solve somehow this?

Comment: Nope, I did not.

Comment: I have this same annoying problem as well!